# Instanziieren vs. instanzieren

Tags: verb, noun

Why has the German **instanziieren** two "i" in the word?

To *instantiate* sth is the process of creating or deriving an object or instance from a template or a class. You often encounter this verb in the context of object oriented programming languages, but it isn't limited to that.

In German, *to instantiate* is often translated *etwas instanziieren* with this strange double "i". It is obviously the verb of the noun *Instanz*. Is *instanziieren* correct, and if yes, why isn't it *etwas instanzieren*?

There are a lot of other nouns like "Replik", "Fabrikation", "Qualifikation", "Differenz" that have the verbs "replizieren", "fabrizieren", "qualifizieren", or "differenzieren". I guess they all derive back to latin "facere", "to do" or "to make", and I don't understand why "Instanz" seems different.

Comment: The word is derived from latin *instantia*. Now, I don't speak latin but it seems like the first i is part of the latin word stem. The second i is part of the German verb ending *-ieren* which often is used to derive a verb from such loanwords. It's really analogous to the English verb *instanti <from latin> -ate <English equivalent to German -ieren>* .

Comment: "I guess they all derive back to latin 'facere'": Why do you think so? Maybe they are over many stages, but they were separate words in Latin before they were borrowed by German: *replicare*, *fabricare*, *qualificare*, *differre*. All of them have no *i* in their stem.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Sorry, I was not precise. I guess that the "-iere" suffix refers to "facere", but this is just guessing, and, to be precise, irrelevant so relevant for the question, since the problem is in the stem, not in the suffix.

Comment: @NilsMagnus Alright! I don't know of any cognation between *facere* and the German affix *-ier-* (+ *-er*, *-en*, *-t* and so on), but in fact it indicates that something is 'made'.

Answer (score 5):

The suffix here is always [*-ieren*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/-ieren). The first *i* comes from the Latin stem.

An example: ***initi**ieren*  is borrow from ***initi**are* (or some derived form). The stem was left untouched, in this case even the *t* is kept (instead of *z*).

Same goes for ***vari**are* –> ***vari**ieren* and ***repatri**are* –> *repatriieren*.

Other examples:

> abbreviieren, affiliieren, alliieren, deviieren, dissoziieren, expropriieren, foliieren,  gloriieren, liniieren, mediieren, negoziieren, plagiieren, pliieren, prämiieren, soziieren, spatiieren, spoliieren, vikariieren

As derivative suffix, *-ieren* is mostly used with adjectives or substantives. Also *substanziieren* and *instanziieren* aren't based on the verbs *substare* or *instare*, respectively, but on the noun forms *substantia* and ***instanti**a*. This is why it is ***instanzi**ieren*. However, it's not always straightforward. E.g., *Differenz* derives from *differentia*, but still we don't say *differenziieren* (but *differenzieren*). This might be due to the fact that the stem of the verb *differre* which *differentia* is derived from doesn't end on *i*.

Comment: Ok, I understand that "instantia" is the Latin base, so that "instanti-a" is the stem and the nominative singular leading to German "instanti-ieren" or, in a more modernized form "instanzi-ieren". However, this does not work with German "Differenz" which refers to Latin "differentia" with the stem "differenti-a", but it is "differenzieren" and not "differenti-ieren" or "differenziieren".

Comment: Another interesting example is "distantia". We say "distanzieren" and not "distanziieren".

Comment: @NilsMagnus RIght.